# Sitecore Javascript Compression / Minification and LESS Compilation

Tags: javascript, sitecore, sitecore6, assets, dotless

Currently, I've been trying to put Cassette into our Sitecore project and it's just fallen flat on it's face. I've had dotLess in the project already, but would like a more solid solution for cache-busting while bundling.

I can use Cassette in a normal .Net4 project, but just can't get it to work in our Sitecore project. (Ed) We were unable to get it to actually build any sort of bundles (checked `/_cassette`) and it wasn't outputting anything to the page. For us, the project isn't built but is instead using CodeFile and I'm not sure if that was part of the problem. In general, we kept getting the `No bundle with path 'xxx'` exception no matter what we tried. It's a bummer to because I would really wouldn't mind having CoffeeScript weaved into the solution.

**Is there a solution that compresses/minifies javascript and can render dotLess files with Sitecore?**

Comment: How come Cassette didnt work with Sitecore ?

Comment: @StephenPope Added detail to the question.

Comment: We got Cassette working with Sitecore but the steps to do it aren't documented yet. One of the main issues was to abort the request pipeline if the request had a route data associated with it (`_cassette`), which requires a custom [small] processor.

Comment: @subkamran I would be delighted to see the processor if you are willing to share.  I would love to try out Cassette for it's dependency/reference resolution.

Comment: @al3xnull, Once I have a local Sitecore instance up and running I wanted to try and implement it myself. A co-worker was the one who did it, so I'll have to ask him if he remembers everything he did. I've only had a chance to poke around the source and figure it out myself. I remember them (the site) having issues with caching where Cassette assets weren't being sent with cache headers. I don't know where that ended up, but we were using the Fx35 branch and now we can use Fx40 finally.

Comment: So I am using a sandbox Sitecore 6.5 install, and I literally just brought down the Cassette 2.0.0-beta5 pre-release package and everything works. I added `/cassette.axd` to the IgnoreUrlPrefixes but I don't think I even need that. I modified the sample layout with the proper Cassette references and I am looking at the default Sitecore homepage with a Cassette stylesheet reference. No additional work needed. I think the main issue was Cassette used to use routing to handle URLs, but now Andrew's switched it to an AXD file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up getting `SquishIt` to work rather easily and without much hassle besides getting the JavaScript files to play nicely together.

Answer (score 3):

The empty response streams from Cassette when working in any of the Sitecore client interfaces are being caused by the `rewriteHtml` functionality that it implements.

By default Cassette will buffer and rewrite page HTML output. This allows partial views to insert `<link>` tags referencing stylesheets after the `<head>` tag has been rendered. The rewrite functionality gets invoked as a `PostRequestHandlerExecute` event handler.

The empty response streams that you are seeing are as a result of the output stream that has been rewritten not being flushed. A fix for this issue is to flush the output stream when Close is called on the `Cassette.AspNet.PlaceholderReplacingResponseFilter` class, this is shown below:

```
    void WriteUncompressedOutput()
    {
        var output = GetOutputWithPlaceholdersReplaced(bufferStream);
        var outputBytes = outputEncoding.GetBytes(output);
        if (outputBytes.Length > 0)
        {
            outputStream.Write(outputBytes, 0, outputBytes.Length);
            outputStream.Flush();
        }
    }
```

If you do not require the rewriting functionality a workaround is available now. Just disable the Cassette HTML rewriting feature, either in the `web.config`:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        ....
        <section name="cassette" type="Cassette.CassetteConfigurationSection, Cassette"/>
    </configSections>
    <cassette rewriteHtml="false"/>
```

or in code:

```
public class CassetteSettingsConfiguration : IConfiguration<CassetteSettings>
{
    public void Configure(CassetteSettings configurable)
    {
        configurable.IsHtmlRewritingEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

This information is included in my blog post about [using Cassette with Sitecore](http://kevinobee.wordpress.com/2013/04/13/cassette-bundling-with-sitecore-mvc/).

Comment: Thank you! This saved me so much grief. I was searching for blank screen in sitecore or white screen of death in sitecore with no luck. Finally narrowed it down to Cassette, and this post saved me. Hope your pull request will get merged soon to the main repo.